# Servlet: different PrintWriter.print() and PrintWriter.println()

Tags: java, servlets, printwriter

```
HttpServletResponse response;
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
out.print("Hello");
out.println("HelloWorld");
```

My question seem silly, but In Servlet, I see that both print() and println() do same thing !!!

If you want to go to another line, you must put `<br>` tag at the end of String.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`println` appends a new line (`\n`) after the printed text. New lines are not interpreted within HTML, therefore you won't see a difference between the output of `println` and `print` within the rendered HTML.

Answer (score 2):

They don't do the same thing. `println` appends an end-of-line marker after the string.

The fact that that end-of-line isn't rendered by browers is another issue. Depending on what content-type you're outputing, it could be significant or not.